# How to validate domain EPP codes?

Tags: dns, domain-name

I'm trying to find a way to automate our company's domain transfer process, and one of the first steps requires validating the domain's EPP code before we initiate the actual transfer.

Currently, we're having to login to our domain registrar and manually use their domain EPP validation tool. They don't provide any API access for this and setting up what would essentially be a macro to automatically log in and run the tool is too fragile for our requirements. The code for their tool is closed source so I'm unable to see how they're validating the EPP codes.

Is there any other method for validating domain EPP codes? I've searched StackOverflow and Google but have been unable to find any information on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

By "EPP code," do you mean the temporary transfer auth codes that registrars usually send via email (or show in their web UIs)?

For reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auth-Code

(EPP codes can also be these status codes, fwiw: https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/epp-status-codes-2014-06-16-en)

I'm also not quite following what you mean by "validating" the codes?

Comment: Yes, the 'auth code' that is required to transfer domains. They aren't temporary, they are permanently attached to a domain. Basically, the domain is the username and the auth code is the password, and both details are required to transfer domains from one registrar to another. If we initiate a domain transfer and the auth code is incorrect then the transfer fails, so before we initiate a domain transfer we use Synergy Wholesale's domain verification tool which takes a domain and EPP code as inputs, then outputs whether or not the EPP code is valid for that domain.

Comment: No, don't confuse "EPP codes" which are really `authInfo` to status codes. They have nothing in common.

Answer (score 0):

An EPP (Extensible Provisioning Protocol) code, also known as an 'Authorization Code', 'Auth-Info Code', or 'transfer code', is typically generated by the domain registry or registrar and can expire. It will normally be between 1 - 32 character long, and will contain at least 1 number, 1 letter, and 1 special character.

Depending upon the Registrar, the EPP code might expire after a certain period of time to avoid security vulnerabilities. If the domain owner requires the EPP code after expiry, they must request or generate it via their domain registrar.

Because the EPP code is used like a password to verify ownership of a domain, it should be secure and inaccessible to third parties, therefore a third party cannot explicitly validate it.

Comment: "and will contain at least 1 number, 1 letter, and 1 special character." Can you give a reference from where that comes from? Because it is untrue. The EPP specifications for `authInfo` are in section 4.2 of RFC 5730 that defines the `pwAuthInfoType` type as just `normalizedString`, which doesn't restrict in any way the content. There aren't restrictions on length either.

Comment: "therefore a third party cannot explicitly validate it." Not true in all cases. A registrar can verify it, in some registries, by domain a domain:info command on the domain with the `authInfo`. The registry reply will differ depending on if the provided password is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the syntax of it, because it is in the EPP specifications, but it is quite lax, so won't help you much (it is just an XML `normalizedString`, there are no restrictions on content or length basically). You may get further constraints detailed by the specific registry, so you need to peruse their documentation or ask them directly (if you can get access to that because it is restricted to registrars most often), but that will differ anyway from one registry to another.

I guess, even if you don't want that as answer, since you say:

> They don't provide any API access

and it means to be a problem for your business, then you either need to find another provider more suitable for your needs, or pressure your current one to give you the tools you need.

If you were a registrar, with direct connection to registry, you could, for some registries, assess if a given `authInfo` (the official name from the specification, that is then often code "auth code" or "epp code" or things like that, but no point in defining new terms) from customer does indeed work,
as a `domain:info` EPP command can specify an `authInfo` and hence done on a domain you don't sponsor yet, the results from registry will change depending on if the `authInfo` is correct or not.

Anyway, even as a reseller, if you start a transfer, you have to provide the `authInfo`. If it is wrong you should get an error immediately, as the registrar sending the command to the registry to transfer the domain will also get an error immediately. And if there is a success instead, it seems the domain has started the transfer and as such proves the `authInfo` was correct.